# Xamarin.iOS UISwitch tap issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uilabel, uiswitch

After the update to Xamarin.iOS 10.2 and iOS SDK 10.2, the UISwitch in my app seems to be hardly tappable (works only if I tap inside the red circle, in the image below). 
Moreover the label (to the right of it) appears ON it despite it has a constraint which should place it at 10 from UISwitch.

[image]

The entire layout is made with storyboard.

Anyone could help me? I've tried everything.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I was able to resolve this by removing these two components and adding them again. The update seems to has messed up the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `UILabel` is in front of the `UISwitch`.

Either set the `UILabel` to not take user input by using this:

`myLabel.UserInteractionEnabled = false;`

or fix the constraint by posting more information on the constraint or uploading the xib/storyboard file.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by removing these two components and adding them again. The update seems to has messed up the layout.

Comment: Awesome glad it was an easy fix

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing these two components and adding them again. The update seems to has messed up the layout.